# Evaluating Wilson loop in Abelian theory (Srednicki)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, regularization, wilson-loop

In chapter 82 https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf
Srednicki comes to the following form for the Wilson loop for free electromagnetic theory:

$$\langle 0|W_C|0\rangle=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}g^2\oint_C dx_\mu\oint_C dy_\nu\ \Delta_{\mu\nu}(x-y)\right], \tag{82.16}$$

where $\Delta_{\mu\nu}$ is the photon propagator in Euclidean spacetime:
$$\Delta_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu}\int \frac{dk^4}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{e^{ik\cdot(x-y)}}{k^2} = ... = \frac{\delta_{\mu\nu}}{4\pi^2 |x-y|^2} \tag{82.17}$$

He then claims that

1. because $\Delta_{\mu\nu}$ is a function of $x-y$, the double integral in 82.16 will yield a factor of perimeter P of the curve C.
2. There is also an ultraviolet divergence as $x$ approaches $y$, which is cut off at a length scale $a$.

The result is
$$\langle 0|W_C|0\rangle=\exp[-(\tilde{c}g^2/a)P], \tag{82.18}$$
where $\tilde{c}$ is a constant that depends on the details of the curve and the cut-off procedure.

I need some more intuition as to the form of this result. How do I see that a factor of perimeter comes out? Why is the divergence $1/a$ rather than $1/a^2$ or something else?

Answer (score -1):

You need calculate double curve integral
$$
\int_C dx_\mu \int_C dy_\nu \frac{\delta_{\mu\nu}}{(x-y)^2}
$$

Firstly we fix x and evaluate y integral. This is divergent integral. So we introduce cut-off $1/a$ and main contribution will be from region where $x^\mu \approx y^\mu$:
$$
\int_C dy_\nu \frac{\delta_{\mu\nu}}{(x-y)^2}
\sim \frac{1}{a} n^\mu(x)
$$
Here $n^\mu(x)$ is tangent vector to curve in $x^\mu$, so:
$$
\int_C dx_\mu \frac{n^\mu(x)}{a} \sim \frac{1}{a}  P
$$